# Is there a known algorithm to solve these kinds of problems?

Tags: algorithm

If I have an object that stores an array of numbers less than N and a weight. Examples of these are as follows:

```
{1,2,4} -> 10
{1,4}   -> 5
{5}     -> 4
{3}     -> 8
{2}     -> 9
```

So in this case N is 5. My problem is that I want to find the maximum sum of the weights such that the numbers in the array are only used once. For instance, if i wanted to sum the weights 10 and 5 corresponding to {1,2,4} and {1,4} this would be illegal as they both contain a 1.

A dumb (and wrong) algorithm would choose {1,2,4} then {3} then {5} to give 22. which is not the answer in this case. An extension to this would be where we can obtain the correct answer 26 then find the next largest sum without considering the objects already chosen(in this case 10 trivially).

Comment: how many arrays of numbers you have, how many items can a single array hold, how many items in total, how high can weight be?

Comment: There is no bound on the number objects I can have. A single array (corresponding to an object) can have as all N numbers in it if it wishes. the weight can be any natural number.

Comment: Solving Maximum (weighted) Set Packing with Integer Linear Programming is an entire field of study, too big to be contained in an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing sounds like the [maximum set packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing). Finding an optimal solution is NP-complete, but algorithms exist which can find an approximate solution; see the references in the Wikipedia article for further information. Alternatively, for problems as small as the one shown in your question, an exhaustive search is trivial.